# How to abort thead after a timeout running DriveInfo.IsReady on bad drive

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

I am aware that aborting thread should be avoided, but in this case DriveInfo.IsReady on UI thread is never returned and program freezes.

I have found several SD card readers that cause this issue (each card slot that does not have a card in it will freeze program checking isReady property (or any other).

```
foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
    if (drive.IsReady)
        DriveCollection.Add(drive); 
}
```

Is there a way to give each drive a second to respond, and cleanly kill the thread, while keeping UI responsive at all times?

Comment: Try wrapping that code in a `try catch`, maybe you're getting `IOException`

Comment: @JohanP I have tried. If I put a breakpoint in IsReady it stops there but then F10 to step over never continues to the next line

Comment: Do you have any network drives?

Comment: @JohanP No, it is definitely SD card reader connected via USB. If I unplug it program works. I have had reports from several users that program freezes when they refresh the drives, so there other readers with the same issue. I have another USB card reader that doesn't produce this issue, just returns false for empty card slots.